# Auto playing songs in a list?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I read through a tutorial and created a simple music player dubbed `SimplePlayer`. When I click the song I want to play, it plays perfectly fine.

However, when that song finishes, instead of playing the next song it plays the second song in the list, then keeps playing it over and over again.

I know that the choosing of the song when the first song finishes is inside the `onCompletion` method with the `mp.setDataSource`, but I'm not sure what I need to put in the brackets other than the `+1` so that it plays the next song in the list:

```
 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        try { 
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(+1));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            play.setEnabled(false);
            pause.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
```

Here is the rest of the code in case I have to change something there as well:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnCompletionListener {
private static final String SD_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/");
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
private View play;
private View pause;
private View stop;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updatePlaylist();
    play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    pause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    stop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    play.setEnabled(false);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    try { 
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        play.setEnabled(false);
        pause.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setEnabled(true);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void updatePlaylist() {
    File home = new File(SD_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter())) {
            songs.add(file.getName());
        }
    ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song_item,songs);
    setListAdapter(songList);
}
}

  public void play(View view){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing song", 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       mp.start();
       play.setEnabled(false);
       pause.setEnabled(true);
       stop.setEnabled(true);
       }



  public void pause(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing song", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mp.pause();
      play.setEnabled(true);
      pause.setEnabled(false);
      stop.setEnabled(true);
   }    


  public void stop(View view){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopping song", 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          mp.stop();
          play.setEnabled(false);
          pause.setEnabled(false);
          stop.setEnabled(false);
  }


 @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        try { 
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(+1));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            play.setEnabled(false);
            pause.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

also, how can I make it so that when the app runs, it lists all songs on the sdcard, the phone storage and in the folders on the sdcard? At the moment it only lists the songs on the root of the sdcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is for continuously playing second song.
You need to use a global variable to indicate song number and increment it and pass that to `setDataSource();`

First,create a public global variable

```
public static int SONG_NUMBER=0;
```

In your onCompletion method

```
 @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        try { 
            mp.reset();
            if(SONG_NUMBER == songs.size())
            {
             SONG_NUMBER=0;
            }
            else
            {
            SONG_NUMBER=SONG_NUMBER+1;
            }
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));// pass SONG_NUMBER++ instead +1
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            play.setEnabled(false);
            pause.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

In your on ListItemClick method,assign SONG_NUMBER based on position

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    try { 
        SONG_NUMBER=position; //   <------------------------add this line 
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        play.setEnabled(false);
        pause.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setEnabled(true);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made the changes and now it just plays the same song continually. Also, is there any way to make a second directory in which the app locates the songs off of both of the directories and puts them both into the one list?

Comment: I changed a line and added another in the `onCompletion` method, `mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER + 1));`          `SONG_NUMBER = SONG_NUMBER +1;` now it works perfectly. Do you know how to make it so that the app will locate all the songs on both the sdcard and the phone storage and add them together into one list?

Comment: [Click here for doing that ..getting songs from different directories and put them into single list](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

Comment: went to the last song and it played through then the app force closed unexpectedly, how do I make it so that at the end of the list, it goes back to the start and plays them again?

Comment: check for number of songs in list everytime..... if(SONG_NUMBER==list.length()-1) then SONG_NUMBER=0; else SONG_NUMBER++; do that

Comment: `public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp1) { try { mp.reset(); mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER + 1)); if(SONG_NUMBER < (SONG_NUMBER - 1)){ SONG_NUMBER = SONG_NUMBER + 1; } else { mp.start(); SONG_NUMBER = 0; } mp.prepare(); mp.start(); play.setEnabled(false); pause.setEnabled(true); stop.setEnabled(true); next.setEnabled(true); }' is this what you meant?

Comment: actually you need to compare with total number of songs in your list...as soon as you enter your `onCompletion()` method check for the condition..